# Css Import not working jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I'm having problems, my css is not displaying on index page.

At index page, i included

Assets is the folder where are all my sass files, at assets:
all.sass(will include all the others), 3-sections (sections from my website).
Inside 3-sections : _header.sass

at all.sass

```
@import '3-sections/header'
```

at _header.sass

```
body
    background:pink
```

I check my index page, and nothing happened. What i did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your _config.yml :

```
sass:
  # loading path from site root
  # default to _sass
  sass_dir: assets
```